# Intersecting arrays based on multiple query parameters

Tags: ruby, arrays, sinatra, parameters, query-string

`@data`, `@x`, `@y`, and `@z` are all arrays of the same type. I use @data in my view to iterate through it and display all the values.

```
  @data = if params[:a] == "1"
    @x
  elsif params[:b] == "1"
    @y 
  elsif params[:c] == "1"
    @z
```

What I'd like to do is also intersect the arrays if multiple parameters are applied. So, for example, if `?a=1&b=2` is appended to the URL, then I'd like `@data` to equal `@x & @y`

I'm not sure how to write this code – what's the easiest way to figure out which params == 1 and then intersect the corresponding arrays and store that in @data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, Ruby makes this easy!

```
@data = [params[:a] && @x, params[:b] && @y, params[:c] && @z].compact.inject(:&)
```

This constructs an array of either arrays (if the parameter is present; you could check `== '1'` if you wanted to be more specific) or nils (if it is not present). `compact` then strips the nils out of the array, and we can then intersect the remaining values by calling `inject(:&)`.

The `inject` call iterates over your array of values, takes the first value, and then applies the `&` method with the next value as a parameter. It then takes the result and applies `&` with the third parameter, and so on, resulting in a final value which is the intersection of all of the arrays in the passed array.

Comment: wow thanks! can you explain this for me a bit? how does this actually check params[:a] == "1"? also, what does compact.inject(:&) actually do?

Comment: It does not check if `params[:a] == "1"`, so if `params[:a] == "0"` or something else except nil and false, it will still include it.

Comment: oldergod is correct; I've modified my answer a bit to clarify that. However, based on the original question (where the values 1 and 2 were passed), I guessed that you were more interested in the presence of a value than in a specific value.

Comment: @ChrisHeald: that's right – just checking the param exists is good enough. this is fantastic, thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
key_to_array = {:a => @x, :b => @y, :c => @z}

@data = key_to_array.select { |k, _| params[k] == '1' }.values.inject(&:&)
```

※ Does not work in Ruby 1.8